# Crystal Report Error on C# Windows Form Application : Failed to Open the Connection

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports

I have developed a  C# windows form application which includes Crystal Reports as well. The Data Base is MySQL.  When I publish my application to the client computer. Crystal report not loading and getting an [error message](https://prntscr.com/kfcnwy). On the developed PC everything  working fine. Can any one advice me on this Please. 
[Code for Crystal Report](https://prntscr.com/kfcsqp)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvwQu.png)

Comment: Preview the report from Crystal Reports designer and check if the report loads.

Comment: Thanks, I checked Crystal report open though Report designer on client computer as well. On Crystal report designer it's working. But on the C# Windows application Crystal report viewer it's getting the error message. ( Failed to open the connection)

Comment: Please help me on this